# Setting the font in a Java Buffer Strategy

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, awt, bufferstrategy

I am currently trying to create a game for a school project and I have come up with an annoying bug.

When I try and set the font in a buffer strategy, it doesn't load and any drawing after the setFont doesn't get drawn...

Here's my code:

```
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
if (bs == null){
    createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}
Graphics s = bs.getDrawGraphics();
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)s;
g.drawString("OldFont (This shows on the canvas)", 20,20,null);
g.setFont(font1);
g.drawString("NewFont (This doesn't show at all.",50,50,null);
```

Font font1 is a pre-loaded font which is a custom font which I have pre-loaded in a jar.

I'm a stumped and have no idea what to do. Any help?

Comment: No exceptions get thrown?

Comment: Nope, nothing is thrown. It's not an error, it just stops there and does the whole thing all over again.

Comment: Try defining `font1` after creating the buffer strategy.

Comment: Like I said, it's a pre-loaded font so it is loaded and defined in the class...

Comment: Can we see a bit more code? Where is this snippet from, a method?

Comment: Yes, it's from a render() method.
To be honest, that's the only code you need...

Comment: I really don't see a problem then, your window is likely larger than 50x50 so that is not an issue, my guess would be that the font is null.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention it's in a while loop. I don't know why this is happening though?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).